# Does Sabre provide an award seat availability API?

Tags: sabre

As the question states, I am interested in accessing an API that will check award seat availability for a set of flights (Specifically Delta, United, American Airlines). My goal is to use this in conjunction with something like Bargain Finder Max so I can list flights that have award seat availability and regular seat prices.

I am brand new to Sabre and appreciate any advice on if this kind of data is possible or available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any airlines publish their award inventory into any GDS system. TMC agents generally have to call the airline to search for inventory and redeem miles.

Comment: ExpertFlyer works directly with the GDSs to provide this information. It may not be available in their public API and something that would need to be contracted directly. That's why I'm asking the question to see what's the case